# Java to Cpp code conversion: compareTo

Tags: java, c++, oop

I have a little problem. I have to convert Java code to C++ code. I have in one java class list of some objects. In C++ I have vector with same purpose. But, i have a problem in this line of Java code:

```
if(compareTo(m.roba.get(i), m.roba.get(j)) == -1)
```

m is object of class, roba is lista (from Java). Return from that list is type of string (it's some names). So how to do same thing i C++? I tried this:

```
if(strcmp(m.roba.at(i), m.roba.at(j)) != -1)
```

in C++ but I get error: "no suitable conversion from "Roba" to "char" exist"

I forgot to mention that list roba is type of Roba class. Same for C++

Comment: You said that return type from the Roba list is String and below you said that roba is of type Roba class ? which one is correct ? It will be easier to help if you post your Java Roba class (or definition if it is indeed a java list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `m.roba.at(i)` defines a `<` operator in a way similar to `std::string`, you can change this to

```
if (m.roba.at(i) < m.roba.at(j)) {
    ...
}
```

Unlike Java, C++ allows writing custom comparison operators. That's how C++ lets you write comparisons of custom objects in a more natural way - instead of explicitly invoking the `compareTo`, you can use the `<` operator. Here is how the operator can be defined:

```
inline bool operator< (const Roba& lhs, const Roba& rhs) {
    // Comparison logic goes here
}
```

Comment: hm...I'm getting this error: "no operator "<" matches these operands"

Comment: @v0idmp3 You need to define the operator then - take a look at the update. The code from `compareTo` goes in for the comparison logic, returning `true` when `lhs` is less than `rhs`.